# Using unavailable screen framerates

Tags: windows-7, display, fps

I know I have weird problems, but: I want to set my screen framerate lower than it allows me.

I have one laptop screen and one attached screen. The attached screen doesn't update all pixels at once, so when I scroll, it looks weird because the parts of the text are at different heights and don't even stay at the same speed. So I wanted to lower the framerate so that this effect is less noticeable and maybe there are also problems with the transmission from the laptop to the screen, so I want to test if a lower framerate resolves that.

But: In the display menu my only options are 59Hz and 60Hz, the entire list is just True Color and High Color in different resolutions, all with 59 or 60 fps.

So how do I set the framerate to 30?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: "The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem." Well, I explained my original problem: Asynchronous lines while scrolling. But: 1. I wanted to test if it's because of the connection speed or just because of how the screen is built. 2. I find it interesting to know if can be done anyway, even if it isn't related to the lines. 3. There are many reasons you might want to lower the screen fps, for example if you try to record something very fast and want to see exactly the same on the screen and in the 30fps recording.

Comment: New comment, because I can't edit anymore: 4. Yes, I didn't think about asking about the screen first, because I suspect a hardware problem.

Comment: fps & screen refresh rate are not related at all. It's your graphics card that's struggling, not the screen.

Comment: Sooo... What should I do?

Comment: You'd need to add your machine & graphics models & current drivers for a better guess, but first approach would be check for driver updates from the *maker of your GPU* not MS or your computer maker.

Comment: Laptop: Intel Core i7-4810MQ, System: Win7 Enterprise+SP1, Screen: HP E242, Driver: Don't really know how to get that, it's from Intel and has many options. Version number seems to be 6.1.7600.16385. But I mainly thought there would be a command that takes a number as refresh rate or a registry key that I can set to any number.